# Angular.js unit test "inject()" fires before a "run" phase block

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, mocha.js, karma-runner

I have a scenario where I am trying to load HTML5 Audio for mobile devices and this can only be achieved through user interaction (e.g. ontouchstart). I have implemented this logic in an Angular run phase as to ensure it is attached at the earliest opportunity. I cannot attach this in the config phase as it has dependencies on other Angular factories:

```
angular.module('MyModule')
    .run(['Device', 'ResourceManager', 'ExceptionFactory', function (Device, ResourceManager, ExceptionFactory) {
        if (!Device.browser.features.webaudio) {
            var onFirstUserInteraction = function () {
                var sounds = ResourceManager.getSounds();

                if (sounds.length > 1) {
                    throw ExceptionFactory.create('Html5AudioLimitReachedException', 'Html5 Audio Devices can only load one sound resource');
                }

                if (sounds.length === 1) {
                    sounds[0].createBrowserAudioObject();
                }

                document.documentElement.removeEventListener(Device.browser.is.IE ? 'click' : 'touchstart', onFirstUserInteraction, true);
            };

            document.documentElement.addEventListener(Device.browser.is.IE ? 'click' : 'touchstart', onFirstUserInteraction, true);
        }
    }]);
```

I have the following unit test failing because the event handler above has not been registered in time:

```
beforeEach(function () {
    angular.module('Html5SoundLoaderApp', [])
        .run(['Device', 'ResourceManager', function (Device, ResourceManager) {
            Device.browser.features.webaudio = false;
            ResourceManager.addSound('testOne', 'test/url/testOne.mp3', {});
            ResourceManager.addSound('testTwo', 'test/url/testTwo.mp3', {});
        }]);

    module('Html5SoundLoaderApp');
});

it('should only be able to load one sound resource', inject(['ExceptionFactory', function (ExceptionFactory) {
    var spy = sinon.spy(ExceptionFactory, 'create');

    expect(function () {
        angular.mock.ui.trigger(document.documentElement, 'touchstart')
    }).to.throw();

    spy.should.have.been.calledOnce;
    spy.should.have.been.calledWith('Html5AudioLimitReachedException', 'Html5 Audio Devices can only load one sound resource');
}]));
```

I would have expected the run() block to have completed execution before the test started? Am I wrong in this assumption? If so how is it best to tackle this situation?

Thanks

Comment: why are you defining a module inside your test? your test should contain mocks and your tests. `module('Html5SoundLoaderApp')` might be returning a function and you might want to invoke it.

Comment: Hi @idursun. This isn't directly related to my question, but thank you for responding. So if I were to take this approach, I would have to mock every single service/factory in my code base? This means I would have to maintain two lots of code as most of the components are re-used throughout the application? Unless I have mis-understood?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code looks asynchronous to me (since it is waiting for a user interaction, for one thing), so use the `done()` callback:

```
beforeEach(function (done) { // <--- Add this parameter.
    angular.module('Html5SoundLoaderApp', [])
        .run(['Device', 'ResourceManager', function (Device, ResourceManager) {
            Device.browser.features.webaudio = false;
            ResourceManager.addSound('testOne', 'test/url/testOne.mp3', {});
            ResourceManager.addSound('testTwo', 'test/url/testTwo.mp3', {});
            done(); // <--- It looks to me like this is where done() should be called.
        }]);

    module('Html5SoundLoaderApp');
});
```

You have to use `done()` for any work that is perform asynchronously. Otherwise, Mocha just marches on forward without waiting for the work to be performed.

Comment: Thanks @Louis! This was indeed the reason why the test was firing before the run block had completed. However, I have taken note @idursun comments above and I have re-factored the event listener into a it's own service and I am mocking out the device and resource manager services. Thanks to both of you.